# How can I get to Libouchec (Ústí nad Labem) from Prague?

Tags: public-transport, czech-republic

I'm currently in Prague and after I check out of my hotel I will go to Libouchec in Ústí nad Labem, but I just don't know the best way to get there

Google Maps will only direct me to Ústí nad Labem train station via the EC172 train. What's the best way to get to Libouchec from there? Both Uber and Bolt apps say that they are unavailable in Ústí nad Labem

I don't mind paying for a local taxi if that sort of thing exists.

Comment: There were taxis in Usti pre-pandemic.  Google does provide contact details of current taxi businesses.

Comment: You might check [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com) for other possibilities.

Comment: For queries about public transportation in ČR, use idos.cz (https://idos.idnes.cz/en/vlakyautobusymhdvse/spojeni/).

Answer (score 1):

I hope you had good time in Prague. The best way is to take a bus or train. See:
https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Prague/Libouchec?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=question-cheapest-oneway#r/Train-via-Praha-Podbaba